# How to dynamically create a none existing page in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-routing, redirect

I am working on a project and i am putting SEO in mind, the smartest way around this will be to dynamically create a none existing page.

**Details**

i have a list of towns

1. Texas
2. Delhi
3. Toronto
4. Sydney

This are links that look like http://xxxxx.com/texas

**Note:**there is no file named texas.php

I have a template page that fetches from the database base on the town clicked on.

I want the link to look like this http://xxxxx.com/schools-in-texas

That should display a page with the template showing results from database after querying the DB with the work "texas"

this should apply for other towns e.g http://xxxxx.com/schools-in-toronto

Comment: Take a read of [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As your question is, there are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should route any Not Found pages to a php script.

In you `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then you can get the URL as a string and get the part you need.

for example if you visit yoursite.com/Texas the following script will return `/Texas`:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
```

and you can do any further work on database...

(The htaccess code got from the Laravel's)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use apache's mode-rewrite rules. With that you could parse your URL and set your GET-String parameters to be used in your controller file that is responding to your page request.

Here is a simply tutorial:
[Mod-rewrite tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/)